# Matrix with base 1

Tags: ruby, matrix

Class Matrix is base 0. I'd like to refer to a matrix element or a row in a matrix using base 1 while still preserving the capability of the existing methods. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite `Matrix#[]`.

```
require "matrix"

class Matrix
  def [](i, j)
    @rows.fetch(i - 1){return nil}[j - 1]
  end
end

Matrix[[25, 93], [-1, 66]][1, 2] # => 93
```

Comment: Should I overwrite or inherit the Matrix class?

Comment: If you would want to switch between base 0 and base 1, it is better to inherit so as to not mess up the Matrix class. If you are always using base 1, then you can overwrite it.

Comment: I override 3 methods: [](i,j), row(i), and col(i).  Are there any other method that I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Possible using [*`Matrix#each`*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-each) and [*`Enumerator#with_index`*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index)

```
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[ [1,2], [3,4] ].each
m.with_index(1){|e,ind| puts "#{e} at #{ind}" }
# >> 1 at 1
# >> 2 at 2
# >> 3 at 3
# >> 4 at 4
```

You can also do this using [*`Vector`*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) class and [*`Matrix#row_vectors`*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-row_vectors):

```
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[ [1,2], [3,4] ]
r_v = m.row_vectors().each
r_v.with_index(1){|e,r| p "#{e.to_a} at row #{r}"}
# >> "[1, 2] at row 1"
# >> "[3, 4] at row 2"
```